# Convert strange 5 digit number to normal Date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have numbers like **42946** in a database column and i want to format it as a normal Date like **dd/mm/yyyy**.
I was searching a lot but i dont find anything usefull.

I tried to do `TO_DATE(<date>,'J')` but this doesn't work beacuse i think **42946** is the number of days between today and January 1 of 1900, and this method works only for dates that are between today and January 1 of 4712 BC.

I hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i think 42946 is the number of days between today and January 1 of 1900

You mean, number of days **since** 1st of January 1900?

If so, you don't have to do much - just add that value to date you specified and you'll get the result. Its (result's) datatype is `DATE` so you can display it any way you want, using the `to_char` function (or any other option you prefer):

```
SQL> select date '1900-01-01' + 42946 as result from dual;

RESULT
----------
01.08.2017

SQL>
```

---

Example of formatting it:

```
SQL> select to_char(date '1900-01-01' + 42946, 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english') as result from dual;

RESULT
-----------
01-aug-2017

SQL>
```

Comment: It should be tested thoroughly, because if this value was taken from some Excel file then it may incorrectly count non-leap 1900 year and require `date '1899-12-31'` as a reference date

Comment: Can't tell, @astentx. Oscar *thinks* it is 1st of January 1900. Maybe it is some other date, instead. We can't know that (if Oscar doesn't either), but - thank you for the comment.

Comment: Yes, it's not about the solution, but about possible issues. "It should be tested" was meant to pay attention and perform additional validation against the known date in this format.